# How can you move the frame of the selection area when in selection mode in Gimp on OSX?

Tags: macos, gimp

The [official guide](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tools-selection.html) says that you have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to move the selection frame, while creating it.

However, on OSX pressing the <kbd>Option</kbd> key does not move the selector frame while you are dragging it, but simply resizes it. Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> does not do anything either.

Is there a way to move the selection frame?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you start to drag inside of the current selection frame, but outside of one of the resize handles (that is, the corners and edges that get highlighted if you hover over them), then your selection frame moves without any modifier. I guess this is what you are actually seeing, and I suspect you get the resize because you are dragging one of the handles.

The Alt key can be used to do this without dragging inside of the selection frame, this can be useful if the selection is very small at the current zoom level.

Sorry, no idea what Alt maps to on OSX/macOS.